# Click element by available id

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a strange case where Angular element is rendering html with 2 random IDs:

```
WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        System.out.println("Click on Sub Tab " + title_id + " using id locator " + tab_id);
        WebElement webElement = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("mat-tab-label-5-0")));
        webElement.click();
```

OR

```
WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        System.out.println("Click on Sub Tab " + title_id + " using id locator " + tab_id);
        WebElement webElement = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("mat-tab-label-3-0")));
        webElement.click();
```

The order is random and I need some way to click on the available id. Is there some way to combine then for example:

```
By.id("mat-tab-label-3-0" OR "mat-tab-label-5-0")
```

Is there some solution?

Comment: Are you automating your own application or someone else's?

Comment: Someone else app. I can't change the source code.

Comment: Can you use xpath?

Comment: partial xpath is not working.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Yes, id is not found.

Comment: @PeterPenzov If you can share the relevant html of the element then answers may be different and precise

Comment: The below solution works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to a CSS selector.

```
ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#mat-tab-label-3-0,#mat-tab-label-5-0"))
```

`#` indicates an ID and `,` indicates an OR.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming those 2 listed are the ***only*** 2 ID's that show up, but it is random which ***one*** shows up, you can try this:

```
WebElement webElement = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("mat-tab-label-3-0" | "mat-tab-label-5-0")));
```

Comment: Is it possible to use try-catch to solve the issue?

Comment: Sure, that's another route you can go

Comment: This is not a valid ID.

Comment: can you give me  cod example please?