# Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.id (tried for 25 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Angular application which I want to automate using Java and Selenium Web Driver. I use this code to validate button label:

```
WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 25);
System.out.println("Validate Button " + name + " label using id locator " + buttonId);
WebElement webDriverElement = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(buttonId)));
assertEquals(webDriverElement.getText(), name);
```

In graphical mode it's working fine. But when I try to run it into background into Headless Chrome mode I get exception:

```
Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: warehouse.all.accessorial-charge.image (tried for 25 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

Stack trace

```
    org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: warehouse.all.accessorial-charge.image (tried for 25 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
at org.mobile.LoginScreenTest.verifyMainMenuLandingScreenTest(LoginScreenTest.java:453)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: 
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#warehouse\.all\.accessorial\-charge\.image"}
(Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DTXA-ENVTEST01', ip: 'xxxxxxx', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_291'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 90.0.4430.212, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 90.0.4430.24 (4c6d850f087da..., userDataDir: C:\Users\devadmin\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:64771}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 6a8fcf1bb88ab7730d0a674104a846d6
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=warehouse.all.accessorial-charge.image}
at org.mobile.LoginScreenTest.verifyMainMenuLandingScreenTest(LoginScreenTest.java:453)
```

Is there some better way to validate button label?

Comment: what is `buttonId` ? is it `#warehouse\.all\.accessorial\-charge\.image` ?

Comment: Yes, I detect it by in my case.

Comment: did u try with `Thread.sleep(5000);` just to check it that works, we can remove that once it works

Comment: no, it's failing randomly. Looks like I need some other way to get the id.

Comment: Yeah, Can I have few part of HTML ?

Comment: Here is a page example: https://pastebin.com/u1hAZKh8

Comment: I could not locate `warehouse.all.accessorial-charge.image`

Comment: It's into another page but the idea is the same. I gave this page because it has less code.

Comment: see this error `Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#warehouse\.all\.accessorial\-charge\.image"}` are you using css in place of id.

Comment: oh... yes. This is related to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67796429/click-element-by-available-id

Comment: Anyway what is the best way to validate button label?

Comment: this depends on the HTML, `id` is always preferable followed by name, linkText, tagName, partialLinkText, cssSelector and then XPATH and class name also.

Comment: Can you give me code example please?

Comment: elementToBeClickable(By.id... you can replace right?  here id, and other locators.. I don't have any doc reference for that, probably in python I can give you https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: yes, I can replace it.